# how can i configure a message handler based on the environment in webapiconfig.cs file?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, webapi2, message-handlers, delegatinghandler

I am using Aspnet webapi2. I want to register a message handler based on the environment. can you please let me know how can i configure the same based on environment.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            if (Env.Equals("Live"))
            {
                config.MessageHandlers.Add(new NotAcceptableConnegHandler());
            }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this by adding a key in config and retrieving the same. not sure though if its best practice.

Comment: Can you put your code here? It is difficult to say without code.

Comment: i need to update my if condition.